# Which gym workout routine after home training?

Tags: workout, gym, routine

I do 6 series x (although I have often long periods of time between series) 20 push up, 10 pull up and 20 chin-up 4 times/week and run 10 km 3 times/week and stopped adding more reps(but I can do more) since 2 weeks ago.

To put my exercises to next level, I decided to go to gym and I'm now looking for workout routine, which should be not complicated nor to much time consuming(not more than 1h in gym/day).

I plan to workout for increasing strength and muscle grow and running for lowering body fat percentage(I'm not obese, nor very skinny, just skinny male) not necessary endurance/durability(I know, I know I was probably doing it bad by large number of repetitions).

What workout routines can you suggest, will stronglifts 5x5 be good for me?

Comment: Stronglifts would be exactly perfect for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stronglifts 5x5: an effective program?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/stronglifts-5x5-an-effective-program)

Answer (score 1):

Stronglifts is definitely a good program for beginners. However, because it is based on powerlifts it will take some time before you can use it optimally. If you're thinking long term heavy barbell training, it's definitely the way to go in my opinion, but if your goals are more short term I would also suggest something like [insanity](https://www.lifestyleupdated.com/insanity-workout-review/) or just at home workouts.

Don't be fooled by the mainstream fitness media though. Most of those models invested years in their bodies.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend HIIT based strength training, maybe 3-4 days a week. This way, you get in enough cardio (as you work until fatigue) and enough weight training to build endurance, strength and size (everyone wants more size).

Here is a [Busy Man's Total Body Workout](http://www.menshealth.com/best-life-magazine/exericse-anywhere) from Men's Fitness

Here is a [3 Circuit Routine](http://www.mensfitness.com/training/workout-routines/3-circuit-fat-loss-workout) (personal favourite)

I would recommend you subscribe to Men's Health and Men's Fitness and regularly checkout routines at the respective places to keep it fresh.

Happy Hunting.